# How to pass varargs into a method as an expanded list?

Tags: flash, variadic-functions

Given the following Flash method:

```
function sendToJava(name:String, ... args)
{
  ExternalInterface.call("sendCommand", name, args);
}
```

How do I ensure that ExternalInterface.call() interprets args in its expanded form? Right now, if I pass a list into "args", that list gets interpreted as a single argument of type "Object[]" by ExternalInterface.call(). When the arguments reach Java, I have no way of differentiating between multiple arguments separated by commas versus a single argument containing commas as part of its value.

Comment: This is only relevant to ActionScript 2, correct? This should be clarified - just a "Flash" tag is pretty ambiguous at this point.

Comment: @IQpierce, what tag is appropriate for ActionScript2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One small typo.  It should be:

```
function sendToJava(name:String, ... args)
{
  // See Array.unshift()
  args.unshift("sendCommand", name);

  // See Function.apply()
  ExternalInterface.call.apply(null, args);
}
```

Just change "array" to "apply"

Anyways, thanks a ton for posting this.  You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on IRC :)

```
function sendToJava(name:String, ... args)
{
  // See Array.unshift()
  args.unshift("sendCommand", name);

  // See Function.apply()
  ExternalInterface.call.array(null, args);
}
```